# How do I call a function with a struct in C?

Tags: c, function, struct, call

I am trying to make a "Langton's ant program".
I have defined a struct:

```
typedef struct Ant
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int b;
}Ant;
```

And I have a function:

```
int st(Ant *ant, int len, char (*area)[len]);
```

But when I try to call this function inside the main function using

```
int main()
{
   [..... ]



   char r[l][l];

   Ant ant;
   ant.x = 0;
   ant.y = 0;
   ant.b = 2;

   st(Ant *ant, l, r);

   return 0;
}
```

I get an error: expected expression before 'Ant'.

I don't see where the problem is. Does someone know what's wrong. I am very new to coding.

Thanks

Comment: You should, at least, post `r` definition?

Comment: BTW `st(Ant *ant, l, r);` --> `st(&ant, l, r);`

Comment: After the edit `int st(Ant *ant, int len, char (*area)[len]);` --> `int st(Ant *ant, int len, char area[len][len]);`

Comment: Sidenote: Using the completely equivalent `char area[len][len]` for the parameter declaration documents better what your function expects. This is only for humans, but those are who have to work with source-code.

Comment: The error is on the line that the compiler points at. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: If your problem is solved, you could accept one of the three answers so that the question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function `st` takes a pointer to `Ant` as a first argument, so you need to pass the address of your variable `ant` (as with `*` you actually indicate the contents of `ant`).
Change the following line :

```
st(Ant *ant, l, r);
```

to :

```
st(&ant, l, r);
```

since the function's prototype is :

```
int st(Ant *ant, int len, char (*area)[len]);
```

---

Although your prototype does not need to change, you could also take a look at this one, to make your code more self-documenting :

```
int st(Ant *ant, int len, char area[len][len]);
```

Comment: @Marievi  Why does he need to change the function prototype?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I was writing two alternatives but forgot to mention both, edited.

Comment: @Marievi As  StoryTeller pointed out you could suggest to use the alternative prototype for self-documentation. In fact there is no need to change the prototype because the function declarations are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

In C, * is used to with a variable holding address to get the value at that address, while & operator is used to get the address  of a variable.
Function definition - `st(Ant *ant,int len, char (* area)[len])` means that first argument should be a pointer to  struct Ant.
So you need to change your function call from -

```
st(Ant *ant,l,r)
```

to -

```
st(&ant,l,r).
```

Also there is no need specifying the type when passing arguments in function call.

Answer (score 3):

When you are accessing stucture members using pointers -> operator is used instead of . operator.

try using this:

```
ant->x=0;
ant->y=0;
ant->b=2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of C programming language,

In `C programming language`, there is difference between defining a function, declaring a function and calling the function.

Defining a function is where you actually provide a definition (what the function actually does) between { } like so:

```
//this is a definition
int addTwo(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b
}
```

`Declaring` a function is simply telling the compiler about the function. You let it know it exist by providing the name, the return type, and the number of / type of arguments.

```
//this is a declaration/prototype
int addTwo (int a, int b);
```

However, to call any such function which has been declared before, we need to pass the variables of right types in right order as specified in function declaration (`Compiler` just hate those who confuses him).

```
// To call addTwo
int first = 5;
int second = 10;
int result = addTwo(first, second);
```

You haven't specified the type of variable `r` in your code. I am assuming it to be of type `char (*)[len]`. To fix your code, change the line:

```
 st(Ant *ant, l, r);
```

To

```
 st(&ant, l, r);
```

Comment: The OP will have to take the address of the array, in order to pass it to a function expecting an array pointer parameter.